# Refactoring Code Between Projects Results in RuntimeException: Uncompilable Code

Tags: java, user-interface, exception, controls, lwjgl

When I copied over my Gui classes from another project to my new one, I thought it would be easy.  Unfortunately, it wasn't.  I made a game named Entwine, who's package name was `net.jibini.entwine` and the new project's package name is `net.jibini.pilgrim`.  When I attempt to run the refactored code (taken from Entwine and put into Pilgrim), I get this error: 
`java.lang.RuntimeException: Uncompilable source code - package net.jibini.entwine does not exist`.  I can not find any link back to the original classes, so I don't know where this is coming from.

This is my base Gui class:

```
package net.jibini.pilgrim.gui;

/**
 *
 * @author zgoethel12
 */
public abstract class Gui {

    public abstract void render();

}
```

This is the GuiPause class:

```
package net.jibini.pilgrim.gui;

import net.jibini.pilgrim.Main;
import org.lwjgl.opengl.Display;

/**
 *
 * @author zgoethel12
 */

import static org.lwjgl.opengl.GL11.*;

public class GuiPause extends Gui {

    GuiElementButton back, quit;

    public GuiPause() {
        controls();
    }

    @Override
    public void render() {

        glPushMatrix();
        glTranslatef(0, 0, 10);

        glBegin(GL_QUADS);
        glVertex2f(10, Display.getHeight() - 10);
        glVertex2f(440, Display.getHeight() - 10);
        glVertex2f(440, 10);
        glVertex2f(10, 10);
        glEnd();

        if (Display.wasResized()) {
            controls();
        }

        glTranslatef(0, 0, 1);

        back.render();
        quit.render();

        glPopMatrix();

    }

    public void controls() {

        back = new GuiElementButton(20, 20, 400, "Back");
        quit = new GuiElementButton(20, Display.getHeight() - (back.height + 20), 400, "Quit");

        back.onClick = new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick() {
                Main.instance.gui = null;
            }
        };
        quit.onClick = new OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick() {
                Main.instance.exitGame();
                Main.instance.gui = new GuiMainMenu();
            }
        };

    }

}
```

And lastly, this is how I set the Gui in the game:

```
if (pressedI.contains(Keyboard.KEY_ESCAPE)) {
    if (gui == null) {
        try {
            gui = new GuiMainMenu();
        } catch (ExceptionInInitializerError err) {
            System.out.println(err.getCause());
        }
    } else {
        gui = null;
    }
}
```

Since it happens with every Gui I try to show, I think that it may be a problem with the base Gui class or the call to `controls();` in the constructor.  I would like to know what the problem is and how to fix it and would appreciate any help!

Regards,
John Smith

Answer (score 1):

The solution to my problem was to go to "Project Properties > Compiling" and disable "Compile on Save"